# Running main loop 2 times with conditional statement

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm trying to achieve simple result. Run main loop 2 times, but first time for the one post with different layout, and second time for the rest posts with different layout. I found that condition **1 > $wp_query->current_post** can show only the first post in my loop. But when I run loop again it starts with 3rd post and skipping the 2nd.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Full Post -->
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        // first post
        if( 1 > $wp_query->current_post ):
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
        else :
            break;
        endif;
    endwhile;
?>

<!-- Small Posts -->
<div class="row">
    <?php
      while( have_posts() ) : the_post();    
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/post-small', get_post_format() );      
      endwhile;
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: a: there is usually no need to run the loop twice just to show the first post different; the conditional would be enough to use a different template part for the first post, and would also work to insert the additional html tags. b: if running the loop twice, use `rewind_posts()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts between the loops.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to put `wp_reset_postdata();` after your first `endwhile;` so that the loop can return to the start.  Can see more about that function here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata

Comment: As I know wp_reset_postdata(); will reset only secondary loop, not the main loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try reading up here: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops and in particular the section here: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action and the use of: `$do_not_duplicate`

Comment: In the example you provided they use custom second loop. I know that's easy way, but I'm trying to use only main query here.

Comment: OK - then look at: `post__not_in` here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters eg: `$second_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post__not_in' => $first_query ) );`

Comment: But again, it's an example with custom WP loop, which I try to avoid. The main query is if ( have_posts() ) : ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); which I try to modify and it works, but for some reason WordPress skips second post in query and start with third.